# Insert randomly increased date hour and list array

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, random, dateadd

I have some gps lat lng  points seperated with `,` some of them

```
  28.964783549308777,41.00934982475349,0
  28.964102268218994,41.00941054477526,0
  28.9627343416214,41.00958865651625,0
  28.96224081516266,41.00963318437629,0
  28.961591720581055,41.0096412803476,0
```

that I have about 1K rows. (I can remove `,0` it is not needed)

My column has lat,lng,date, speed. I want to add them with this lat lng and randomly increasing time and random speed.

Example of time first one is 2013-10-21 12:03:20 second one 2013-10-21 12:03:23 third one 2013-10-21 12:03:25. The second must be increase between 2 and 5 second randomly.

Speed must be change between 20 and 35 totally random.

How can I combine all of them and insert automatically?

Comment: thanks for everyone who helped me

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = GETDATE()

;with dt as (
SELECT CAST(1 as int) as ID, @StartDate as dtime,CAST(20+ROUND(15*RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())),0) as int) as speed
UNION ALL
SELECT ID + 1, DATEADD(SECOND,2+ROUND(3*RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())),0),dtime) , CAST(20+ROUND(15*RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())),0) as int)
FROM dt
WHERE ID <= 1000)

SELECT *
FROM dt
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
GO
```